# Java Hbase Client check table exists log information

Tags: java, hbase

I write a Java Program to insert data into HBase. If I just simply using

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
table.put(put);
```

the hbase log in console is find; however, if I put a "check table existing condition" before that, like

```
if(admin.tableExists(tableName))
{
     HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
     table.put(put);
}
```

The HBase log in console displays more weird information

```
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=catalogtracker-on-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@11957996
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /127.0.0.1:2181
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: The identifier of this process is 23872@localhost
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x44558c9b8f009f, negotiated timeout = 180000
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x44558c9b8f009f closed
14/03/04 11:29:26 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

There is no error showing but it repeats to display this useless info every time when the program do the table checking, so you can imagine the hbase console output looks like if I have millions of data to insert.

Could anyone tell me how to avoid HBase displaying this useless info (I have to check the table is existing or not before inserting)? I just want to make the console more clean.

Comment: So are you saying your code is working fine, but you want to get rid of the console output? Also, it isn't useless info...

Comment: Yes, my program is working fine. I just want to get rid of these info from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the logging level displayed on your console in HBase's `log4j.properties`. It is set to INFO by default, you can change it to something higher (WARN/ERROR), which will stop HBase from writing INFO level logs to the console.

Alternatively, you could make HBase print the logs into a File instead of the console, that way your console would be clean.

Here are the properties you should modify in `log4j.properties`:

```
hbase.root.logger=INFO,console
hbase.security.logger=INFO,console
hbase.log.dir=.
hbase.log.file=hbase.log

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO
```

Comment: I change the log level to WARN and restart the cluster but it still displays the info. I don't understand why.

Comment: did you change the log level for all zookeeper related properties? From your console output above, all the log entries are zookeeper related.

Comment: OK I find the solution. Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN);